# Making responsive panels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ettmujvg/11/)

I'm trying to follow this idea of creating a dashboard using bootstrap :

https://www.behance.net/gallery/6355085/dashboard-analytics

And now I've got [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ettmujvg/11/)

But then I realized that the panels's height is not the same on different browsers.

In Firefox:

[image]

In Chrome :

[image]

And if i zoom in, they are not adjacent to each other anymore:

[image]

*A little code I have to add to fit SO's rules:*

```
#righthalfHorizontalPanel{
    width: 45.5%;
    margin:5px 8px 0px 0px;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid;
    min-height:290px;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the css code like below:

```
#pBody{margin-left:105px; padding-right:8px;}
#halfHorizontalPanel{margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;}
#lefthalfHorizontalPanel{margin:8px 0px; width:50%; }
#righthalfHorizontalPanel{margin:8px 0px; width:50%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ettmujvg/17/

Comment: Thanks alot Cattla, you saved me again. 

Can I ask one more thing about the height? I don't want to set it in pixel, can I set it in percentage? That way I don't have to worry about other display size?

Comment: @hoangnnm you want lefthalfHorizontalPanel and righthalfHorizontalPanel are the same height all the time?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to make them fit the body's height, so on different browsers and devices, they all look good

Comment: is this because you can set table's height by percentage?